# react-routers take two - six times to redirect to other pages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, react-navigation

**(Problem) react-router takes two to six times to redirect to other pages**

Here is Link which I'm clicking.

```
<div className='drawer-item' onClick={this.drawerItemClicked}>
     <BinaryLink to={link_to}>
          <span className={icon || undefined}>{text}</span>
     </BinaryLink>
</div>
```

When the item (Link) is clicked, `drawerItemClicked` is triggered.

```
drawerItemClicked = (e) => {
    this.props.hideDrawers();
    if (this.props.collapseItems) {
        this.props.collapseItems();
    }        
}
```

And at the same time, `BinaryLink` is triggered

```
export const BinaryLink = ({ to, children, ...props }) => {
    const path  = normalizePath(to);
    const route = getRouteInfo(path);
    console.log('to');
    console.log(to); <- triggers continuously
    if (!route) {
        throw new Error(`Route not found: ${to}`);
    }

    return (
        to ?
            <NavLink to={path} activeClassName='active' exact={route.exact} {...props}>
                {children}
            </NavLink>
        :
            <a href='javascript:;' {...props}>
                {children}
            </a>
    );
};
```

Here is the Router class

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/',          component: TradeApp, exact: true },
    { path: '/statement', component: Statement, is_authenticated: true },
    { path: '/account',   component: LostPassword, is_authenticated: false },
];

const RouteWithSubRoutes = route => (
    <Route
        exact={route.exact}
        path={route.path}
        render={props => (
            (route.is_authenticated && !Client.isLoggedIn()) ? // TODO: update styling of the message below
                <a href='javascript:;' onClick={redirectToLogin}>{localize('Please login to view this page.')}</a> :
                <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
        )}
    />
);

export const BinaryRoutes = () => routes.map((route, idx) => (
    <RouteWithSubRoutes key={idx} {...route} />
));
```

Something went horribly wrong. But I am unable to troubleshoot.

The output from `to` keeps calling routes.js because it's rendering current time from server. However, even if I delete it, it doesn't work.

```
...
routes.js:48 undefined
rroutes.js:47 to
routes.js:48 undefined
routes.js:47 to
routes.js:48 undefined
routes.js:47 to
routes.js:48 undefined
routes.js:47 to
routes.js:48 undefined
routes.js:47 to
routes.js:48 undefined
routes.js:47 to
routes.js:48 undefined
```

**My thought** Definitely something is wrong where I defined `<NavLink>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was CSS error. The `<a>` tag didn't take the whole space in `div`. I hope this solves others' issues.